# Using FetchContent to retrieve Protobuf and gRPC to compile during build (hermetic)

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to make a standalone CMakeLists.txt file that will build/install protobuf/gRPC. I'm writing a blog post on gRPC stuff and my readers might not want to install protobuf/gRPC to play around with the code in the post.  So I'm trying to entirely use cmake's `FetchContent` to download protbuf and gRPC, compile them, and use them to build the other code in the project. (Users will want to simply copy and past the CMakeLists.txt without installing the libraries system wide.)

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the code to compile. After scouring many resources this is what I've got now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(command_server)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  absl
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
  GIT_TAG        origin/master
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(absl)

FetchContent_Declare(Protobuf
  GIT_REPOSITORY git@github.com:protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
  GIT_TAG        v23.3
  SOURCE_SUBDIR  cmake
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Protobuf)

FetchContent_Declare(
  gRPC
  GIT_REPOSITORY git@github.com:grpc/grpc
  GIT_TAG        v1.55.1  # e.g v1.28.0
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gRPC)

find_package(absl REQUIRED)
FetchContent_GetProperties(Protobuf SOURCE_DIR Protobuf_SOURCE_DIR)
include(${Protobuf_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake)

add_library(proto OBJECT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/helloworld.proto")
target_link_libraries(proto PUBLIC protobuf::libprotobuf)
set(PROTO_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated")
target_include_directories(proto PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}>")

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET proto
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=$<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>"
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(my_exe greater_server.cc)
target_link_libraries(my_exe grpc++ proto)
```

However this spews tons of errors like:

```
CMake Warning at build/_deps/absl-src/CMakeLists.txt:77 (message):
  A future Abseil release will default ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD to ON for CMake
  3.8 and up.  We recommend enabling this option to ensure your project still
  builds correctly.


--
-- 23.1.0
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/grpc-src/third_party/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Found systemd via pkg-config.
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotobuf-lite" which requires target "absl_absl_check" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotobuf-lite" which requires target "absl_absl_log" that is not in any export set.

... snipped ...

CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_memory" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_node_hash_map" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_node_hash_set" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_optional" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_span" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_status" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_statusor" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_strings" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_synchronization" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_time" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_type_traits" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_utility" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "protobuf-targets" ...) includes target "libprotoc" which requires target "absl_variant" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "utf8_range-targets" ...) includes target "utf8_validity" which requires target "absl_strings" that is not in any export set.
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is reported in issue https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/12185, a workaround is given by https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/12185#issuecomment-1594685860.

Using CMakeLists.txt like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(command_server)

include(FetchContent)
set(ABSL_ENABLE_INSTALL ON)
FetchContent_Declare(
  absl
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
  GIT_TAG        origin/master
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(absl)

...
```